# This JsonSerializerOptions instance is read-only or has already been used in serialization or deserialization

Tags: c#

I'm tryin to reuse `JsonSerializationOption` in many places and this is my code:

```
    public static void ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        jsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        jsonSerializerOptions.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);
        jsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
        jsonSerializerOptions.ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip;
        jsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode;
        jsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        jsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
        jsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
    }

    private static JsonSerializerOptions options;

    public static JsonSerializerOptions Options
    {
        get
        {
            if (options == null)
            {
                options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
                ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(options);
                options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            }
            return options;
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll but was not handled in user code: 'This JsonSerializerOptions instance is read-only or has already been used in serialization or deserialization.'

How can I check it? It does not have a `IsReadOnly` property.

Comment: The code you show here would not give the error you are getting. That will only happen if you try to modify the options object after it has already been used in [de]serialisation.